# Combining overlapping 3D models

Tags: 3d

I used a 3D scanner to generate several 3-dimensional models of rooms in a building. I need to combine all of these models to form a complete map of the building, but I haven't found any programs that can do this yet. This is similar to [image stitching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching), though it needs to work with 3-dimensional models instead of 2-dimensional images.

Ideally, I'd prefer to use an open-source program to reconstruct the 3D map.

Comment: I know you'd said "ideally open-source" but for my money, I'd be looking squarely at Unity for this task.

Comment: This sounds like something [CloudCompare](https://www.danielgm.net/cc/) can do...

Answer (score 0):

What kind of format can you export in? If you can go to one of the commonly used formats (as if you were exporting from Blender, etc) you could then import into one of the free game engine map maker tools like GtkRadiant/NetRadiant.

As a bonus you then have the excuse to install Xonotic/Quake3/etc on the office machine so you can use the game engine for "testing" your models :)

Comment: Is GTKRadiant/NetRadiant able to automatically merge overlapping parts of 3D models, or would I still need to edit the models manually?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I believe that you can in fact have models/chunks/building blocks embedded/overlappign each other.  I know the last similar product I used - QuARK (same deal for Quake2 maps) back in the late 90s supported it.  I know Unity3d can do it, but you did say you wanted open source.